# Xampp - mysql - Cannot create file xampp-control.ini, Access Denied

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I use xampp for one month. But xampp yesterday  started making trouble like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTyyg.jpg. That I uninstall and now install xampp and my sql is running. But now if i want to run xampp and click to xampp icon I always have to choose language: english / german. And if I want to end the program and I stop mysql, I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQyfL.jpg (* Access Denied) and this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2H4Ja.jpg Then I must wain for program answer. I can end xampp. How to repair to normal working again? Thank´s

Comment: "+1" Maybe this post is more helpful:[Error: Cannot create file xampp-control.ini Access is denied](https://devnote.in/error-cannot-create-file-xampp-control-ini-access-is-denied/)

Answer (score 42):

[image: xampp access denied control ini]

The issue is with the permissions, just give write access to the file, you will not get error while you try to exit xampp ...
It worked for me ...

Comment: "+1" Thank you. Also read [Error: Cannot create file xampp-control.ini Access is denied](https://devnote.in/error-cannot-create-file-xampp-control-ini-access-is-denied/)

Answer (score 9):

Deleting the file and executing `xampp-control.exe` is also working.

`xampp-control.exe` will recreate the `ini file` with all the correct permissions.

Comment: This is the most elegant answer!

Comment: simple and elegant :)

Answer (score 8):

xampp-control.ini file somehow become 'read only'. Just changing it to '**full control**' solved my problem.

Comment: That's the perfect solution. Running as Admin is kind of annoying.
But I wonder the permissions of the .ini file got changed!

Comment: When I clicked on properties of that file, Read only was unchecked. But when I went to security tab it was marked as read only for Everyone. I made it full control for Everyone. That resolved my issue. Thanks for showing the correct path.

Answer (score 4):

Error caused due to incorrect xampp-control.ini file permission.

**In order to fix this issue in a simple way:**

- Open **xampp** folder > delete **xampp-control.ini** file
- Run the **xampp** application, it will recreate the **xampp-control.ini** file with proper file permission.

Now your application should look good.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was solved by just running the app as an administrator.

Right click the xampp control panel, and then run as administrator.

You can send to desktop the xampp control panel (shortcut), then change permissions to always Run As Administrator[my image] , [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPQ8F.png)

and use the shortcut in everywhere you want to add (maybe in your taskbar)

Answer (score 3):

It happens because the owner of `xampp-control.ini` is different than your user. A simple solution I did was to:

1. copy it
2. paste it somewhere
3. copy it back to the original location

This way your user will become the owner of the file. No need to run `Xampp Control Panel` as Administrator which then prompts you each time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just the xampp control panel as an administrator and its done.
Right click on **xampp control panel** and select run as administrator, your issue will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution is to locate the file xampp-control.ini in C:\xampp, right-click, select Properties then the Security tab and Edit the permissions to Allow all permissions for Everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for this error cannot create file "c:\xampp\xampp-control.ini" acces denied

Rightclick on xampp-control.ini and click on property then click on security and click on EDIt and give full control on EveryOne.

Answer (score -1):

1. Find file **xampp-control.ini** into folder XAMPP
2. **changes permisssion for everyone with FULL CONTROL**